# Mod rewrite and dynamic URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i know this is a common question but i cannot figure this one out.

I have the following URL:

```
http://buildsanctuary.com/viewbuild.php?id=3&title=this_is_a_title&page=1
```

What i wish is the URL to be:

```
http://buildsanctuary.com/viewbuild/3/this_is_a_title/1
```

Normally for mod rewrites i would send the user to the link i want and let htaccess do all the work.

So in this case i have tried linking the users to the preferred URL style and rewriting the URL but to no avail.

Any help on how i should be handling this? I want to send the users to the preffered URL but then can i use htaccess to allow me to process the page and URL $_GET information in the same way as the normal dynamic URL?

I have tried the mod rewrite generators etc but nothing works.

This is what the gens have given me:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /viewbuild.php?id=$1&title=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post what you have now?

Comment: I think you should end up passing the path, e.g. `3/this_is_a_title/1` to PHP and do the mapping there.

Comment: Your missing the [QSA](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) flag

Answer (score 0):

Fix the generator rule:

```
RewriteRule ^viewbuild/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /viewbuild.php?id=$1&title=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

However, I would do it this way:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*) /$1.php/$2 [L]
```

and then map what you get in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to you preference in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2&title=$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick

^viewbuild/([0-9]+)/([a-z_]+)/-([0-9]+)/?$ viewbuild.php?id=$1&title=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]